# Leaflet geoJSON - function within setStyle()

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, style, angular

I have 2 styling methods for countries on my map:
`style_init()` for the initial style of a country,
`style_new()` for when a country changes and I want to re-style it on the map:

```js
style_init(feature: any)           style_new(feature: any)
{                                  {
    return {                           return {
        fillColor: '#ffffff',              fillColor: '#000000', // new style here...
        color: '#ffffff',                  color: '#ffffff',
        ...                                ...
    };                                 };
}                                  }
```

I'm successfully using `style_init()` when initialising the map:

```js
this.map_layer = L.geoJSON(this.countries, {
    style: this.style_init
}).addTo(this.map);
```

To update the style of a country, I'm currently embedding the style code into `setStyle()`:

```js
this.map_layer.eachLayer(function (layer: any)
{
    if( layer.feature.name == target_country )
    {
        layer.setStyle({
            fillColor: '#000000', // currently using raw style code here...
            color: '#000000',
        });
    }
});
```

I'm using `setStyle()` instead of `.addTo(map)` because the countries have already been added and I don't want to remove and re-add them or add a new country over the top of the existing initial country.
However, I want to use my `style_new()` method within the `setStyle()` call, like this:

```js
this.map_layer.eachLayer(function (layer: any)
{
    if( layer.feature.name == target_country )
    {
        layer.setStyle({
            this.style_new() // using my function here instead
        });
    }
});
```

But trying this produces errors such as:
`':' expected`
`'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation`

How can I make `setStyle()` use my predefined function, instead of having the write the explicit style code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `style_new` function returns style object, it must not be embedded in the object specifiers `{}` when you call it, so code should look like this:

```
this.map_layer.eachLayer(function (layer: any) {
  if( layer.feature.name == target_country) {
    layer.setStyle(this.style_new());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried this but Angular now throws an error:
`'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation`.
Is it because I'm using a `this.` within a different `this.` ?

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with Angular, I can't help you with the right function call there, but it should be basic Angular stuff.